# Xamarin Live Previewer for Native Android / Native iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I know there is *Live Previewers* available for `Xamarin.Forms` so you can view your `xaml` markup on a real device instantly, however is there any *Live Previewers* available for `Native Android` and `Native iOS` using `Xamarin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Traditional Xamarin it gets even better, you have designers for Android if you use AXML files to create your UI (see documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/designer_overview/)). For iOS, there is also a designer available when you use Storyboard files (documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/)).

So, you do not only get a preview of what it looks like, you are able to actually drag-and-drop actual controls on there and style them through the property grid.